# how to keep samples in valid clusters?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have 72 sample in my datExprSTLMS as gene expression dataset and ran clustering on this data set based on below code:

```
new_hclust = hclust(dist(datExprSTLMS), method = "average")
Cutreecluster_Sample <- cutreeDynamic(dendro = new_hclust, minClusterSize = 5,
                                          method = "tree")
```

and then I got table as below:

```
table(Cutreecluster_Sample)
Cutreecluster_Sample
 0  1  2  3  4 
 1 24 22 18  7
```

Now, sample in cluster by 0 is the outlier and I would like to remove it from my dataset.
so I run below code for keeping all samples except the sample is in cluster 0

```
keepSamples = (Cutreecluster_Sample==!0)
```

but when I run table for keepsamples I see below result:

```
> table(keepSamples)
    keepSamples
    FALSE  TRUE 
     48    24
```

As you see in `keepSamples` I have just 24 samples instead of 71 samples. 
I appreciate if anybody guides me in code level for solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `keepSamples = (Cutreecluster_Sample==!0)` to `keepSamples = (Cutreecluster_Sample!=0)`

Why? Evaluating your command from right to left: `!0` is a logical negation of `0`, which is equivalent to `!FALSE` in R. Thus `!0` is equal to `TRUE`. You then check if `Cutreecluster_Sample` equals `TRUE`. `TRUE` coerced to numeric is `1` in R. Thus your check is actually `TRUE` iff samples are in cluster 1, not cluster 0.

Try `!0 == 1` and `FALSE == 0`.

Comment: Thank Dear @alanocallaghan. I have more question. suppose if I want to choose samples in cluster 1 and 2. So what will be my code for "KeepSamples"?

Comment: I would do `keep <- Cutreecluster_Sample %in% c(1, 2)`

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it has helped you